# Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process, clean-up

The Stack Exchange user interface now prevents creating tags that differ only in hyphenation or pluralization. This hasn't always been so, however, and there are currently many such tag pairs, like [log-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-files) and [logfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logfiles), or [digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digits) and [digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digit), or [menuitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menuitem) and [menu-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu-items).

Let's clean up!

Clean up means, for each such tag pair:

1. First decide whether the tags really mean the same thing. There are false positives in this list. [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window) have nothing to do with each other. Most of the hits are good, though.
2. If the tag names really mean the same thing, decide which name to keep. There are several general principles:

   - For multi-word tags, [a hyphen is preferred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/tags-foobar-versus-foo-bar).
   - There is no consensus for plural vs. singular for nouns. [This old thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41501/tagging-as-singular-or-plural) very weakly suggest the singular, and among popular pairs the singular is dominant, but recent practice tends towards plural.
3. If it has been decided that a tag T2 should be merged into a tag T1, then:

   - If there are a lot of occurrences of T2, suggest or vote for a tag synonym, which will eventually lead to the tags being merged.
   - If there are only a handful of occurrences of T2, then we can get rid of T2 manually.

Please observe some ground rules:

- **Do not retag if you aren't sure** that you're doing the right thing. If you aren't sure whether two tags mean the same thing or which name to keep, **[ask on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)** and try to get people competent in the subject matter involved. If you aren't sure which community(/ies) uses a tag, check the “Related tags” box in the right-hand column.
- If you find a tag that looks ambiguous, or a useless tag that should be removed, or a tag that indicates off-topic posts, take appropriate action. [Ask on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) or get advice in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) if you aren't sure what to do.
- If you retag some posts manually, don't *just* change that one tag: take the time to do any other warranted improvement (other tags, spelling, formatting, etc.). If you see a question that should be closed, vote or flag it.
- If you know what a tag is about, and it doesn't have a tag wiki yet, **write a tag wiki**. This is especially important when you see a pair of similar tags that are not synonyms: inform the world of what the tags mean.

I've listed all the tag pairs that are concerned by this clean-up in two answers below (postprocessed from [this Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/72948/tags-with-similar-names)):

- **[Tag pairs that differ only in hyphenation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251479)**
- **[Tag pairs that differ in apparent pluralization](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251480)**

(Please keep the score of these answers at -1, so that any new answer to this question is easily visible.)

Comment: Has this process failed to take effect? Many of the singular/plural tag combinations still exist. Plus the tag voting and synonym suggestion system isn't helping a concerted effort to clean up because many tags I'm not allowed to vote on or suggest synonyms despite it being absolutely clear that they mean the same things (ie [tag:sprite] vs [tag:sprites]).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D What process are you talking about? There's a process that prevents **new** pairs from arising. This thread is about cleaning up the **old** pairs.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, the old pairs are still here, the thread is 2.5 years old by now. I can't say when sprite vs sprites have been added, but I'm sure they've been around for a while yet I've only recently suggested sprites being a synonym for sprite. Maybe I've been looking at the wrong pairs though, maybe I have the wrong idea about a concerted effort to "clean up" (ie completed within a few months).

Comment: [tag:getmethod] is winning out over [tag:get-method]

Comment: What should we do once we've cleaned out a tag? Is there a process to automatically delete tags with no questions?

Comment: @divibisan Yes. A tag with no question will disappear from https://stackoverflow.com/tags after a day or so.

Answer (score 34):

I think the other thing to consider is whether or not one of the tags has a wiki associated with it.  For example, [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) has a wiki; [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posts) does not.  Thus, it would make more sense to roll the non-wikified tag into the already established and wiki'd tag.

Also, using this specific example, [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) and [http-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-post) are actually synonyms of each other (based on the tag wiki), whereas [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posts) means something completely different and is possibly full of off-topic questions.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder what happens to wikis when tags are deleted or merged.

Comment: @BilltheLizard They [become orphans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148926/whats-an-orphan-wiki).  (I know that you know bout it now, but just in case some one has the same question)

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bits) (809 questions) and [bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit) (1789 questions)

Related question: [It's a bit confusing that we have both [bit] and [bits] as tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305987/995714)

Answer (score 4):

All but one of the tag synonyms in this post were viewed and synonymized based on the similarity of the tags. If you feel that any of the synonym needs to be removed, or if you need to add a new synonym from one of the non-synonym pairs, please create a new meta post for it.

### Tag pairs that differ only in hyphenation

Here are all the tag pairs that differ only in hyphenation, sorted lexicographically:

TagName Count   TagName Count
[comobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comobject) 131 [com-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/com-object)    41 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[controlpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controlpanel)  91  [control-panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/control-panel) 60 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[controltemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controltemplate)   979 [control-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/control-template)  15 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[custompaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custompaging)  59  [custom-paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-paging) 34 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[decimalformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decimalformat) 447 [decimal-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decimal-format)    20 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[designview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/designview)    28  [design-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-view)   46 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[dropshadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropshadow)    267 [drop-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drop-shadow)   36 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[dynamicmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamicmethod) 91  [dynamic-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-method)    46 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[editcontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/editcontrol)   82  [edit-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edit-control)  9 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[eventqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventqueue)    58  [event-queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-queue)   16 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[eventreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventreceiver) 50  [event-receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-receiver)    124 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[eventvalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventvalidation)   37  [event-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-validation)  5 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[filestructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filestructure) 23  [file-structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-structure)    164 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[flex-mojos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex-mojos)    35  [flexmojos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexmojos) 92 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[formsauthentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formsauthentication)   117 [forms-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms-authentication)  3062 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[getmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getmethod) 98  [get-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/get-method)    31 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[hiddenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hiddenfield)   132 [hidden-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-field)  805 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[lastinsertid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lastinsertid)  139 [last-insert-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/last-insert-id)    156 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[logfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logfiles)  223 [log-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-files) 36 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[lookupfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lookupfield)   24  [lookup-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lookup-field)  10 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[lostfocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lostfocus) 81  [lost-focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lost-focus)    144 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[modalpopup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modalpopup)    103 [modal-popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modal-popup)   31 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[modelbinders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modelbinders)  246 [model-binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-binders) 13 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[multitargeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multitargeting)    44  [multi-targeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-targeting)   30 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[mvcminiprofiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvcminiprofiler)   14  [mvc-mini-profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc-mini-profiler) 374 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[operationcontract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operationcontract) 64  [operation-contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operation-contract)    7 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[oracleclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracleclient)  177 [oracle-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-client) 9 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[partialviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partialviews)  27  [partial-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partial-views) 2384 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[pdfviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfviewer) 89  [pdf-viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf-viewer)    187 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[pop-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop-up)    184 [popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popup) 8659 [**may be exception to 'prefer hyphenated'**]
[propertyeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/propertyeditor)    66  [property-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/property-editor)   15 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[routedevents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routedevents)  15  [routed-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routed-events) 193 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[runloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/runloop)   90  [run-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/run-loop)  11 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[sessionstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sessionstorage)    159 [session-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session-storage)   435 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[singleinstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleinstance)    169 [single-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-instance)   48 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[stateserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stateserver)   58  [state-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/state-server)  8 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[staticresource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/staticresource)    187 [static-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-resource)   73 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[struts1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts1)  196 [struts-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts-1) 1090 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[syndicationfeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syndicationfeed)  35 [syndication-feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syndication-feed) 77 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[threadstatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/threadstatic)  49 [thread-static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread-static) 9 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[topdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topdown)  54 [top-down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/top-down) 45 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[tracelistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tracelistener)  103 [trace-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trace-listener) 15 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[typelibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typelibrary)  18 [type-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-library) 164 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[userlocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/userlocation)  119 [user-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-location) 24 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[usersettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usersettings)  131 [user-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-settings) 41 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[webclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webclient)  3001 [web-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-client) 46 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[webcontent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webcontent)  37 [web-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-content) 79 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[webproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webproject)  33 [web-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-project) 113 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[webusercontrols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webusercontrols)  22 [web-user-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-user-controls) 110 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[windowsformshost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsformshost)  136 [windows-forms-host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms-host) 10 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- For multi-word tags, a hyphen is preferred (ie the version on the right is preferred).
- If a pair has been reduced away, please remove it.
- If it has been determined that both tags must exist, please move the pair to the list below:

### Tag pairs that should stay:

[app-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app-code) (App_code is a bundled folder of ASP.NET)    [appcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcode) (AppCode is an IDE by JetBrains)
[appdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appdata) (%AppData% is a standard Windows directory)    [app-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app-data) (App_Data is a special folder for Visual Studio projects)
[strictmode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strictmode)  103 (Android strictmode)  [strict-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strict-mode) 60 (JavaScript strict mode)

Tag pairs that differ only in hyphenation should be avoided, but if the hyphenated version and the non-hyphenated version do differ in meaning, move them here.

### Tag pairs that need to be discussed/disambiguated before synonymization

[contenttype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contenttype)   87  [content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-type)  1908
[urlhelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlhelper)  101 [url-helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-helper) 24

### Tag pairs where one or more of the tags have been burninated

[datadriven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datadriven)    23  [data-driven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-driven)   117

### Tag pairs that cannot be created due to other conflicting synonym proposals

[typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeahead)  817 [type-ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-ahead) 21

<sub>[SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70822/suspected-substring-tags) courtesy [@reemrevnivek](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/3259/reemrevnivek).</sub>

Comment: Can any of this retagging be done dynamically on the DB level? Like find all `tagA` and replace it with `tagB`. Or/and can these lists be dynamic or at least refreshed every now and then? (unless they already are)

Comment: @Geo Moderators have a tool to merge tags. But before tags can be made, community members must review the potential synonyms to ensure that they are indeed synonyms (we wouldn't want to merge [tag:window] and [tag:windows]!). The list was extracted from the database, it won't grow anymore since it has become impossible to create new such tag pairs (e.g. `foo-bar` or `foobars` can't be created when `foobar` exists).

Comment: [Could we make f-string and fstring tag synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380113/4642212)

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

All the tag synonyms in this post were viewed and synonymized based on the similarity of the tags. If you feel that any of the synonym needs to be removed, or if you need to add a new synonym from one of the non-synonym pairs, please create a new meta post for it.

### Tag pairs that differ in pluralization

Here are all the tag pairs (or occasionally larger sets) that apparently differ only in pluralization (and possibly hyphenation), sorted by the number of occurrences of the most common tag. All these tags have been synonymized.

[view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/view) (4939)    [views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/views) (1966) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controller) (2758)    [controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controllers) (227) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connection) (2133)    [connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connections) (144) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapping) (3242)    [mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mappings) (48) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/client) (1816)    [clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clients) (35) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slider) (1717)    [sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sliders) (50) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/format) (1703)    [formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formats) (32) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/char) (1626)    [chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chars) (60) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[forms-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms-authentication) (1571)    [form-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-authentication) (32) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) (1553)    [words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/words) (153) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings) (1419)    [setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setting) (95) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollbar) (1419)    [scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollbars) (148) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen) (2497)    [screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screens) (48) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/label) (1360)    [labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/labels) (166) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version) (1347)    [versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versions) (136) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override) (1319)    [overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overrides) (34) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overlay) (1274)    [overlays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overlays) (53) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project) (1243)    [projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/projects) (282) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) (1241)    [packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packages) (705) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/line) (1102)    [lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lines) (279) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/driver) (1047)    [drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drivers) (239) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listener) (1045)    [listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listeners) (124) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blob) (1014)    [blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blobs) (40) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/port) (992)    [ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ports) (158) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/element) (988)    [elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elements) (490) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coordinates) (975)    [coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coordinate) (81) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/limit) (948)    [limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/limits) (103) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panel) (947)    [panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panels) (92) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handler) (904)    [handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handlers) (84) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts) (885)    [contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact) (359) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default) (1561)    [defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/defaults) (70) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/external) (875)    [externals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/externals) (39) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/message) (869)    [messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messages) (333)  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/document) (855)    [documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documents) (133) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instance) (845)    [instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instances) (111) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parent) (829)    [parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parents) (34) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cell) (774)    [cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cells) (161) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feed) (745)    [feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feeds) (388) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/state) (738)    [states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/states) (83) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photo) (727)    [photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photos) (287) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toolbar) (706)    [toolbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toolbars) (15) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequence) (702)    [sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequences) (182) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[filestream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filestream) (682)    [filestreams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filestreams) (6) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/profile) (630)    [profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/profiles) (80) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resolution) (611)    [resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resolutions) (11) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polygon) (589)    [polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polygons) (62) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/converter) (582)    [converters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/converters) (28) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition) (581)    [transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transitions) (190)  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relationship) (568)    [relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relationships) (174)  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roles) (556)    [role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/role) (122)  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record) (543)    [records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/records) (192) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixel) (540)    [pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixels) (234) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diagram) (537)    [diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) (57) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forum) (501)    [forums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forums) (87) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formula) (489)    [formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formulas) (47) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helper) (486)    [helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helpers) (286) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/target) (486)    [targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/targets) (66) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/picture) (482)    [pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pictures) (138) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subview) (478)    [subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subviews) (53) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symbols) (462)    [symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symbol) (250) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) (455)    [shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcuts) (212) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/environment) (454)    [environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/environments) (11) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[controltemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controltemplate) (454)    [controltemplates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controltemplates) (22)    [control-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/control-template) (9) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contains) (452)    [contain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contain) (23) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[meta-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags) (447)    [metatag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metatag) (25) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[virtualhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualhost) (440)    [virtual-hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-hosts) (73) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/require) (429)    [requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requires) (4) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/definition) (423)    [definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/definitions) (26) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monitor) (421)    [monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monitors) (22) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[webservice-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webservice-client) (419)    [webservices-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webservices-client) (86) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rules) (408)    [rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule) (109) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handle) (391)    [handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handles) (57) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gesture) (384)    [gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gestures) (187)  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap) (381)    [wraps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wraps) (4)  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[itemrenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itemrenderer) (371)    [itemrenderers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itemrenderers) (8)  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product) (367)    [products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/products) (143) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shape) (366)    [shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shapes) (218) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conventions) (363)    [convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convention) (106) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clock) (360)    [clocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clocks) (3) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[datacontract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datacontract) (355)    [datacontracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datacontracts) (15) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)    
[signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signature) (349)    [signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signatures) (25) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/privileges) (344)    [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/privilege) (16) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packet) (343)    [packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packets) (99) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alarm) (336)    [alarms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alarms) (20) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shadow) (332)    [shadows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shadows) (22) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/predicate) (330)    [predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/predicates) (24) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[google-apis-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apis-explorer)  (326)   [google-api-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-explorer)   (29) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/member) (318)    [members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/members) (63) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metrics) (313)    [metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metric) (28) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeric) (308)    [numerics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerics) (17) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[permalinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/permalinks) (272)    [permalink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/permalink) (78 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed))
[internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internal) (263)    [internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internals) (185) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procedure) (241)    [procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procedures) (52) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit) (237)    [implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicits) (30) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[listboxitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listboxitem) (233)    [listboxitems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listboxitems) (32) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[cstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cstring) (232)    [c-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-strings) (69)    [c-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-string) (6) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/account) (230)    [accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accounts) (68) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[hidden-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-field) (227)    [hiddenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hiddenfield) (40)    [hidden-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-fields) (19) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equation) (226)    [equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equations) (62) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[named-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/named-scope) (224)    [named-scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/named-scopes) (3) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subscription) (223)    [subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subscriptions) (77) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/area) (223)    [areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/areas) (40) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datastore) (219)    [data-stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-stores) (9) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[nsnotifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsnotifications) (217)    [nsnotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsnotification) (89) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[stub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stub) (205)    [stubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stubs) (13) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[modelbinders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modelbinders) (200)    [modelbinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modelbinder) (26)    [model-binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-binders) (8) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[keyevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyevent) (196)    [key-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-events) (40) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[rollover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rollover) (190)    [rollovers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rollovers) (21) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playlist) (185)    [playlists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playlists) (17) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/endpoint) (184)    [endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/endpoints) (69) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[treemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/treemap) (184)    [treemaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/treemaps) (7) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[customvalidator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customvalidator) (183)    [custom-validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-validators) (38) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/region) (180)    [regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regions) (68) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perspective) (175)    [perspectives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perspectives) (27) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[continuations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuations) (173)    [continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuation) (10) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variant) (165)    [variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variants) (7) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fault) (164)    [faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faults) (11) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agent) (161)    [agents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agents) (32) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gateway) (160)    [gateways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gateways) (8) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[treenode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/treenode) (160)    [tree-nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree-nodes) (19) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assertions) (159)    [assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assertion) (98) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curve) (154)    [curves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curves) (22) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subreport) (153)    [subreports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subreports) (23) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restriction) (150)    [restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrictions) (70) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[eventlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventlistener) (142)    [event-listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listeners) (52)    [event-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listener) (32) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manual) (136)    [manuals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manuals) (31) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[windowsformshost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsformshost) (136)    [windowsformhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsformhost) (32) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/demo) (133)    [demos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/demos) (10) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[servercontrols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servercontrols) (132)    [servercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servercontrol) (21) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/figure) (131)    [figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/figures) (26) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[bitset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitset) (130)    [bitsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitsets) (14) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[mouselistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouselistener) (130)    [mouse-listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouse-listeners) (19) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drive) (128)    [drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drives) (29) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[caption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caption) (127)    [captions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/captions) (20) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[quaternion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quaternion) (121)    [quaternions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quaternions) (20) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[keystroke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystroke) (121)    [keystrokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystrokes) (33) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paragraph) (120)    [paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paragraphs) (18) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[scripting-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scripting-language) (118)    [scripting-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scripting-languages) (6)  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[webusercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webusercontrol) (115)    [web-user-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-user-controls) (59)    [webusercontrols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webusercontrols) (13)  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[bitmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitmask) (114)    [bit-masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-masks) (6) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light) (111)    [lights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lights) (12) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[clean-urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clean-urls) (109)    [clean-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clean-url) (6) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digits) (107)    [digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digit) (56) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[nszombie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nszombie) (104)    [nszombies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nszombies) (4) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[eventtrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventtrigger) (103)    [event-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-triggers) (13)    [eventtriggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventtriggers) (3) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[nsdatecomponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsdatecomponents) (102)    [nsdatecomponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsdatecomponent) (7) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[opcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opcode) (102)    [opcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opcodes) (19) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[function-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-calls) (101)    [function-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-call) (53) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[view-helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/view-helpers) (101)    [viewhelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewhelper) (12) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[touch-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch-event) (100)    [touch-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch-events) (35) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[invoice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invoice) (98)    [invoices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invoices) (23) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[spline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spline) (98)    [splines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splines) (13) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[dropshadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropshadow) (97)    [drop-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drop-shadow) (6)    [drop-shadows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drop-shadows) (4) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[particles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/particles) (95)    [particle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/particle) (31) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[routed-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routed-events) (92)    [routedevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routedevent) (38)    [routedevents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routedevents) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (11)
[built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in) (92)    [builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builtin) (39)    [builtins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builtins) (18) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[logfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logfiles) (89)    [logfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logfile) (35)    [log-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-files) (8) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[affiliate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/affiliate) (88)    [affiliates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/affiliates) (9) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[routed-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routed-commands) (88)    [routedcommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routedcommand) (11) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[ajaxform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxform) (86)    [ajax-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax-forms) (14) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[multiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiview) (86)    [multiviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiviews) (11) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operation) (85)    [operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operations) (84) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[member-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/member-functions) (84)    [member-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/member-function) (14) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contract) (83)    [contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contracts) (37) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/segment) (82)    [segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/segments) (38) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[enumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enumerator) (81)    [enumerators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enumerators) (11) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/executor) (80)    [executors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/executors) (23) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[workflowservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workflowservice) (80)    [workflow-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workflow-services) (2) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/measure) (77)    [measures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/measures) (3) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proof) (76)    [proofs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proofs) (4) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rate) (75)    [rates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rates) (7) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[check-constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/check-constraints) (74)    [check-constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/check-constraint) (4) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[symbol-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symbol-table) (73)    [symbol-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symbol-tables) (25) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/favorites) (72)    [favorite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/favorite) (14) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[system-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system-programming) (68)    [systems-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systems-programming) (28) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[form-helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-helpers) (67)    [formhelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formhelper) (39) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[url-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-mapping) (67)    [urlmapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlmapping) (38)    [urlmappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlmappings) (12) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[object-initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-initializers) (67)    [object-initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-initializer) (2) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[avatar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avatar) (67)    [avatars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avatars) (11) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[datamember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datamember) (66)    [data-members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-members) (16) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[network-share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-share) (66)    [network-shares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-shares) (19) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[writer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writer) (65)    [writers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writers) (3) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapper) (65)    [mappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mappers) (4) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letters) (64)    [letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letter) (61) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quota) (60)    [quotas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quotas) (15) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[options-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options-menu) (60)    [optionmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optionmenu) (37) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[out-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/out-parameters) (59)    [out-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/out-parameter) (9) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[indexed-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexed-view) (59)    [indexed-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexed-views) (6) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[callouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/callouts) (58)    [callout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/callout) (27) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[subform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subform) (58)    [subforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subforms) (20) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[update-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/update-attributes) (58)    [update-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/update-attribute) (6) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/details) (58)    [detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detail) (48) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[resource-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resource-files) (58)    [resource-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resource-file) (16) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[virtual-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-method) (57)    [virtual-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-methods) (8) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formset) (56)    [formsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formsets) (17) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[function-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-templates) (56)    [function-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-template) (3) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifier) (55)    [modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifiers) (13) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucket) (52)    [buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buckets) (13) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[extra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extra) (52)    [extras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extras) (39) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[modalpopups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modalpopups) (51)    [modalpopup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modalpopup) (31)    [modal-popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modal-popup) (5) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[templatetags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templatetags) (49)    [templatetag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templatetag) (9) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[voxel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/voxel) (47)    [voxels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/voxels) (10) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[ivar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ivar) (41)    [ivars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ivars) (5) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[helpfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helpfile) (40)    [help-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/help-files) (8) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[aspects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspects) (39)    [aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspect) (33) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[class-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class-attributes) (37)    [class-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class-attribute) (3) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[dataformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataformat) (37)    [data-formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-formats) (22) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[instance-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instance-methods) (37)    [instance-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instance-method) (10) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[data-layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-layers) (37)    [data-layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-layer) (6) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[er-diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/er-diagrams) (37)    [er-diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/er-diagram) (9) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[custom-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-event) (36)    [custom-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-events) (29) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[remote-connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remote-connection) (36)    [remote-connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remote-connections) (7) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[object-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-files) (34)    [object-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-file) (22) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zone) (34)    [zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zones) (10) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[vendor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vendor) (30)    [vendors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vendors) (18) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[hostheaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hostheaders) (30)    [hostheader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hostheader) (10) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[discount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discount) (29)    [discounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discounts) (12) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phrase) (29)    [phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phrases) (11) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[aggregator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aggregator) (28)    [aggregators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aggregators) (13) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[pointcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointcut) (28)    [pointcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointcuts) (25) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[inspection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inspection) (27)    [inspections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inspections) (3) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operands) (26)    [operand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operand) (13) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[servicepacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servicepacks) (26)    [service-pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service-pack) (5) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[fiber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fiber) (25)    [fibers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fibers) (22) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variations) (24)    [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variation) (10) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[powerpacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpacks) (23)    [powerpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpack) (18) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[form-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-fields) (21)    [formfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formfield) (16) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[background-agents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/background-agents) (21)    [background-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/background-agent) (10) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[customtool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customtool) (21)    [custom-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-tools) (6) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pane) (20)    [panes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panes) (12) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[interruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interruption) (20)    [interruptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interruptions) (8) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[controller-action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controller-action) (19)    [controller-actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controller-actions) (9) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Tag pairs that need to be discussed/disambiguated before synonymization

Move tags which are being used for multiple usages here

[global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/global) (730)       [globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/globals) (78)
[local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local) (697)       [locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locals) (26)
[preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preferences) (681)       [preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preference) (140)
[alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alert) (657)       [alerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alerts) (114)
[gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradient) (655)       [gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradients) (36)
[margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/margin) (643)       [margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/margins) (135)
[aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aggregate) (633)       [aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aggregates) (18)
[effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/effects) (476)       [effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/effect) (300)
[tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tiles) (466)       [tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tile) (164)    [tag-disambiguation](/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation)
[partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partial) (427)       [partials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partials) (166)
[custom-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attributes) (408)       [custom-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attribute) (6)
[volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/volume) (400)       [volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/volumes) (13)
[quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quotes) (522)       [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quote) (116)    [tag-disambiguation](/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation)
[ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctypes) (519)       [ctype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctype) (30)    [tag-disambiguation](/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation)
[point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point) (329)       [points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/points) (167)
[fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixtures) (301)       [fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixture) (42)
[dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimensions) (249)       [dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimension) (93)
[marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marker) (209)       [markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markers) (177)    [tag-disambiguation](/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation)
[processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processor) (203)       [processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processors) (21)
[movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movie) (202)       [movies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movies) (22)     [tag-disambiguation](/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation)
[skin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skin) (200)       [skins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skins) (51)
[mkdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mkdir) (186)       [mkdirs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mkdirs) (8)
[channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/channel) (171)       [channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/channels) (17)     [tag-disambiguation](/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation)
[webmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webmethod) (166)       [webmethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webmethods) (138) [tag-disambiguation](/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation)
[git-tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tfs) (160)       [git-tf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tf) (75)
[stocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stocks) (136)       [stock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stock) (86)
[visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visitor) (99)       [visitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visitors) (32)  [tag-disambiguation](/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation)
[windows-messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-messages) (93)       [window-messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window-messages) (24)
[artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artifacts) (81)       [artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artifact) (42)
[dynamic-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-forms) (77)       [dynamicform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamicform) (4)
[hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hint) (69)       [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hints) (32)
[jtemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtemplate) (59)       [jtemplates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtemplates) (10)
[sqlparameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameters) (48)       [sqlparameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameter) (21)
[django-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-filter) (43)       [django-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-filters) (8)
[ordinal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ordinal) (31)       [ordinals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ordinals) (21)
[italic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/italic) (25)       [italics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/italics) (14)
[typed-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typed-arrays) (20)       [typedarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typedarray) (3)

### Tag pairs that should stay

Move false positives here.

[function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function) (67769)   [s-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s-function) (115)
[windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) (33908)    [window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window) (2087)
[http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http) (11548)    [https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/https) (3603)
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) (6707)    [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posts) (171)
[expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expression) (5600)    [s-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s-expression) (34)
[datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) (2732)    [datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) (910)
[order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order) (2725)    [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders) (68)
[scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope) (2315)    [scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scopes) (35)
[smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smtp) (2189)    [smtps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smtps) (6)
[cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursor) (1975)    [cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursors) (215)
[union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union) (987)    [unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unions) (66) (SQL v. C, C++ etc.)
[inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline) (848)    [inlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inlines) (22)  (the latter is a [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) concept)
[frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frame) (840)    [frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frames) (364)
[content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-type) (705)    [contenttype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contenttype) (29)    [contenttypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contenttypes) (8)
[daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/daemon) (688)    [daemons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/daemons) (54)
[extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extend) (372)    [extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extends) (215)
[space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space) (367)    [spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spaces) (241)
[readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readline) (326)    [readlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readlines) (27)  (two different functions, though related)
[host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/host) (321)    [hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hosts) (125)
[rtmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtmp) (308)    [rtmps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtmps) (7)
[imdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imdb) (273)    [ims-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ims-db) (16)
[nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nexus) (269)    [nexus-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nexus-s) (84)
[ios-bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-bluetooth) (166) [iobluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iobluetooth) (80)
[combinators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/combinators)   (154)   [s-combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s-combinator) (8)
[direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/direction) (143)    [directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directions) (70)
[arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow) (111)    [arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows) (45) ([ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340724/should-we-burninate-the-arrow-tag))
[strcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strcat) (63)    [strcat-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strcat-s) (2)  as the later is used for the `strcat_s` function
[custom-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-tag) (56)    [custom-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-tags) (24)
[js-cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js-cookie) (54) [jcookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jcookies) (1)
[slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slots) (38)    [slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slot) (30)
[google-maps-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-react) (36)    [google-map-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-map-react)  (5)
[jedi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jedi) (32)    [jedis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jedis) (24)
[java-ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ws) (30)  [javaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javaw) (22) (Java-WebServices / javaw application laucher)
[inet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inet) (25)    [inets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inets) (14)  (inets is a webserver written in Erlang; the other tag is kind of a mess, though)
[rope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rope) (27)    [ropes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ropes) (11)
[pdfpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfpages) (**matplotlib** method)    [pdfpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfpage) (**objective-c** class)
[cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cube) (218)    [cubes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cubes) (57)
[throw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/throw) (135)    [throws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/throws) (26)
[clip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clip) (114)    [clips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clips) (37)
[getopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getopt) (110)    [getopts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getopts) (27)
[cmdlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmdlets) (77)    [cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmdlet) (33)
[commonjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commonjs) (76)    [commonj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commonj) (17)
[iphone-3gs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-3gs) (66)    [iphone-3g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-3g) (6)
[partialfunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partialfunction) (65)    [partial-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partial-functions) (15)

#### Tag pairs that cannot be created due to other conflicting synonym proposals

[menuitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menuitem) (515)    [menu-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu-items) (9)
[bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bundle) (879)    [bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bundles) (51)
[edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge) (139)    [edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edges) (36)
[genetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetic) (33)    [genetics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetics) (12)

#### Tag pairs where one or more of the tags have been burninated

[slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slide) (476)    [slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slides) (33)
[tableadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableadapter) (193)    [tableadapters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableadapters) (5)    [table-adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-adapter) (5)
[include-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/include-path) (188)    [include-paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/include-paths) (7)    [includepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/includepath) (3)
[level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) (126)    [levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/levels) (50)
[file-association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-association) (120)    [fileassociation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fileassociation) (18)    [file-associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-associations) (3)
[screen-readers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-readers) (96)    [screenreader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenreader) (14)    [screen-reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-reader) (5)
[shell-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell-extensions) (79)    [shell-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell-extension) (22)

Comment: Would these be considered duplicates `html-heading`/`html-head`, `link-tag`/`stylesheet-link-tag`, `canonicalization`/`canonical-link`? Also there is another one - `canonical`. It's different. Though it might be confused with the aforementioned two `canonical`

Comment: @Geo I don't know. You should ask these in separate questions (one question per tag pair or per group of closely related tags).

Comment: Edited to say I'd got rid of all popup inconsistencies, then saw I was looking at the wrong tabs on the tags, and there are actually loads more. So rolled back. Lovely.

Answer (score 4):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

I submit something which may have been missed when this was done:

[map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) (7294) and [maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maps) (3924)

Comment: Both of those tags have different meanings per their tag wikis. I'm trying to think of the best solution there, as there is likely some overlap there. They definitely cannot stay as-is though.

Comment: @animuson Oh damn, I hadn't read that. Damn. They're pretty much all over the place, I bet.

Comment: @animuson Just throwing this out there: Ban both. [tag:maps] as in cartography is substituted for that, [tag:cartography]. [tag:map] as in the data structure is substituted with [tag:mapping]. It's not perfect, I admit.

Comment: I'd excluded tag pairs where the singular was 3 characters or fewer because there were too many false positives that were TLA/FLA pairs, so signaling 3-letter words is good. However, I think [tag:map] and [tag:maps] should stay as tags, though I agree that [tag:maps] could be synonymed to [tag:cartography] (but I don't like [tag:map] → [tag:mapping]: it's not the same concept at all).

Comment: @animuson Is there a lot of misuse? If the tags are used correctly, they can stay.

Comment: @Gilles Then perhaps just synonymizing [tag:maps] to [tag:cartography] should at least fix half the problem.

Comment: @Gilles Ultimately,I think [tag:maps] should just be burninated. It's broad and encompasses a lot of different things. Right off the bat I see Nokia Maps and Google Maps, which are probably not even close to the same thing, but are both being used as their respective tags ([tag:nokia-maps] and [tag:google-maps]) *plus* the [tag:maps] tag. With that done, though, the [tag:map] tag would need to be renamed to *something* more descriptive to *prevent* further abuse. I also see Bing Maps in there, and who knows how many other improper uses.

Comment: @Gilles [tag:map-structure] for clarity? But I'm afraid 99% of newbies will tag them all anyways...