# I do not deserve this Excavator badge

Tags: bug, mso-mse-split

[I just earned an Excavator badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/75/excavator?userid=321731) for editing [this Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags/251479#251479). Thing is the thread was constantly edited, and the latest edit can't be older than a week. The issue must be as a result of the split because it happened after the thread was migrated from MSE.

As a sidenote, the whole Answer lost its history, making my edit looking like the only revision.

Comment: you just earned the `Honesty` badge... See your profile!

Comment: The post is almost 2 years old. You edited it, you earned the badge

Comment: Hrm. The criteria for the badge is for the post to be "inactive for 6 months". Preserving the entire activity history on migration isn't going to happen, and outside of that this is probably not really worth fixing, to be honest, but I'll take off status-bydesign for now.

Comment: @AnnaLear should not the history be preserved: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96398/147166?

Comment: @Tshepang No. See the answer that explains how that feature request is actually fulfilled: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216285/155160

Comment: @AnnaLear does that not only apply to Questions? I can't find history for the Answer.

Comment: True, but either way, preserving the entire history along with the migration isn't something we can do for technical reasons. Hence the partial workaround that's currently in place. It's especially not worth pursuing for the accuracy of a bronze badge in a rather narrow case where an old question is migrated. (Keep in mind that under normal circumstances questions that are older than 2 months cannot be migrated at all.)