# Point of the format tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Can anyone explain the point of the [format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/format) tag? The description contains 9 possible uses, basically copied from Wikipedia. The questions are on a wide variety of subjects, as would be expected, from string formatting, visual formatting, file formats, and even a question on [formatting USB drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361393/unformattable-files).

Is this a pointless tag that could be removed?
Or, it could be split into some nicer tags ([date-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-formatting), [file-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-format), [string-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-formatting)). Er, those tags already exist. So then really, why use the more general tag?

Comment: This is pretty similar stuff: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a pointless tag by itself.

But rather than just getting rid of it you should consider a retagging exercise. There are a quantity of decimal or double to decimal place format questions - these could be retagged as `number-format`. The same can be done for `date-format`, `file-format`, etc.

If you just get rid of the `format` tag then a bunch of these questions will be left with `string` or `double` etc., which is equally useless and lacking context by itself.

Once that is done, the remaining questions which cannot be reasonably retagged can then simply have the tag removed.

Of course it can be up for discussion which tags are most appropriate to be the replacements, that list can be compiled right here. Feel free to edit in suggestions:

> double format    ->|
> decimal format  ->| -> number-formatting
> currency format ->|
>
> date format -> date-formatting
> file format    -> file-format

Comment: `date-format` is a tag for a Java library, but `date-formatting` is an existing tag, for the purpose this is being used for.

Comment: I would edit that in, but it appears that i'm too new to meta to edit posts.

Comment: @Scimonster I've edited that in, I've left file-format as it was because I think that's a more appropriate tag. Let it sit for a while and see if others weigh in with some suggestions.

Comment: `file-format` is an existing tag, so that's good.