# Merge tags: [http-request] and [httprequest]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

As listed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251480/2886003) the [httprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httprequest) (x2357) and the [http-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-request) (x178) and [http-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-requests) (x62) tags are the same.

I would suggest to merge into http-request tag as it is the "standard" way of tagging. And then add the information of the more used httprequest.

Could we merge this two tags? Or is there any other action to simplify it?

Comment: I have retagged all [tag:http-requests] to [tag:http-request], if I remember correctly the tag should be deleted within 30 days or something, should someone make [tag:http-requests] a synomym

Comment: @secretformula, what about `httprequest`?

Comment: @PaulDraper haha thats far too great a task for me to do right now unless there's a better way then going in and changing each tag (all 2k). That is if you don't want me to end up dead :p

Comment: @secretformula, oh...you did that by hand. Wow. Thanks.

Comment: @secretformula Manually, seriously... Wouldn't it have been best to just request they become a synonym?

Comment: @Lankymart twas late, twas stupid, it built character :p. I thought thats the way it had to be done

Comment: @secretformula Possibly, I don't know to be honest but I thought that was the purpose of tag synonyms.

Comment: I think this should be tagged with synonym-request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a synonym (what, no-one even proposed one in all these years?), then approved it.