# The tags [x-window] and [xwindow] are synonyms of [xwindows]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I have noticed they are 3 tags for questions about the X Window System: [xwindows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xwindows) (the most common by far), [xwindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xwindow) and [x-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x-window). I think they should be synonyms.

Since there was only 9 occurences of [x-window], I edited the questions manually to replace the tag with [xwindows], but I wonder if it was the right thing to do. While checking here if this tag was discussed before, I noticed [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags) that says that the hyphen is usually preferred for tags with multiple words...

Since the questions are about the **X Window System** (singular window), I'm guessing the appropriate form of the tag should be [x-window], right? So maybe what should be done is copy the tag wiki of [xwindows] to [x-window], and make [xwindows] and [xwindow] synonyms of [x-window]?

As suggested in the coments we can even get rid of all of them and use [x-window-system] or [x] instead.

Now I feel bad that these couple of edits made me reach the 2k barrier...

Comment: Shouldn't the appropriate tag be either `[x]` or `[x-window-system]`?

Comment: I picked amongst the three existing ones, but indeed since we are at it we might rename everything to [x-window-system]. [x] works too, but [x-window-system] is clearer I think.

Comment: @Fred Shouldn't be just [x]; that's too short to disambiguate and I'm sure there are other technologies called 'x'.

Comment: @Parthian, I suggested it because that tag does not exist on SO and I'm use to call it `X` informally. Not sure about conflicts with other technologies, but I agree plain `[x]` would be a strange sight for non-X-users.

Comment: @robertharvey: Please revoke status-completed. Wooble's answer ammends this question properly.

Answer (score 4):

These should all be synonyms of [x11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x11), which has many more questions than either of these 3.

Comment: True, I missed that one. Actually, [x-window-system] which apparently was used in the past is already a synonym of [x11].

Comment: [tag:xwindow] is ready to be added as a synonym of [tag:x11]