# Merge [imageicon] and [image-icon]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Please merge [imageicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imageicon) (tagged 507 Q&A's) with [image-icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-icon) (tagged 58 Q&A's), both are used exclusively for Java + Swing questions on SO

Comment: Note, this merge falls into the following category: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags