# It's a bit confusing that we have both [bit] and [bits] as tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

I just came across a question tagged with both [bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit) and [bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bits).  There isn't a lot to choose between them.

- [bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit) has a wiki entry that says "A bit is a single binary digit."
- [bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bits) has a wiki entry that says "A bit (a contraction of binary digit) is the basic capacity of information in computing and telecommunications; a bit represents either 1 or 0 (one or zero) only."

They seem to be describing the same thing to me.
There are 1166 questions tagged [bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit) and 522 tagged [bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bits) and 9 tagged with both.

Time for a synonym, I think: [bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bits) should be a synonym of [bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit) ([proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bit/synonyms) submitted — 4 up-votes needed, please).

Any comments or views that seriously disagree?  (If so, maybe you need to down-vote the synonym proposal.)

Comment: What's the required score to vote for a synonym proposal? If it's [higher than 89](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bit/topusers), then I don't know how you're going to get those votes.

Comment: [bit-manipulation] has more questions than either [bit] or [bits], but [binary] has still more.  I don't particularly propose to do anything with any of them, but maybe someone reading this wants to figure out when to use each and fill in the tag excerpts accordingly.  (An excerpt that just defines _bit_ is not useful to very many programmers.)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley [Five net answer score.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

Comment: Ah, okay. The score is counted by votes then, not rep. Seemed a bit off.

Comment: Still not a lot of eligible voters.  My DSO skills are inadequate to get the actual number but there are only 2,631 users with *any* nonzero score for [tag:bit].  What are the odds they will even visit the tag page?

Comment: Those tags have no selective power, every programmer knows something about bits.  They are just contextual tags, an easy way for an answerer to tell that the Q has something to do with bit manipulation without a lot of introduction.  And yes, [bit-manipulation] is another one, 4000 questions.  No need to fix this.

Comment: [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags)

Comment: There is a Microsoft library called BITS for creating auto-updater stuff. Is this what you find used under the `bits` tag?

Comment: @ashes999: I looked at pages 1, 5, 11 (at 50 entries per page), and only 1 entry might be related to that: [VB.NET and BITS — Background Intelligent Transfer Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730129/vb-net-and-bits-background-intelligent-transfer-service) which is tagged [tag:bits] and [tag:bits-service].  The second is plausibly sensible for that question; the first is not.  So, not many questions (<1%).  YMMV, but still not a major topic for bits.

Comment: Although I thought I am a bit of an expert in boolean values, I have not earned enough reputation to vote for the synonym. Sorry, Jonathan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that in general when a word is just a plural it either shouldn't be allowed as a tag, or it should automatically be a synonym of the singular version of the word.

Comment: But that would mean I could never ask a question about my [Links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_%28web_browser%29) browser!

Comment: That would be a case where the tag is a proper noun and not a plural.

Comment: How would you automatically detect whether something is a plural or not (just) a plural? It doesn't seem particularly easy.

Comment: @Dukeling -- Well, first you invent an omniscient AI and then

Comment: In most cases that I'm aware of (though I haven't done a comprehensive survey) the plural form of the tag is preferred. This makes sense, as it's usually more natural to consider a question as being "about bits" rather than "about bit"...

Comment: @Dukeling I think this should be a guideline followed by humans and not necessarily programmatic.

Comment: [There's already an effort to combine singular/plural tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags) (it states that creating plural tags are disallowed).

Comment: Would that count as a pluralization bug? ;) https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Answer (score 22):

A few minutes ago I thought that bit, bits, etc were not useful tag and should therefore be deleted.

Then I looked at the questions on [C#][bit] and found a useful set of questions that are somewhat related to each other.    I can also believe that someone would be an expert in [C#][bit] and therefore search on the combined tags.   (The same can be said for java, vb.net, french, etc.)

I think that we just need [bit-manipulation] and that [bit]/[bits] should be merged into it.