# Do we need to talk about Tag pluralisation?

Tags: discussion, tags, plurals

- We have plural tags for variables ([variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variables)), forms ([forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms)) and loops ([loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops)).
- We have singular tags for dates ([date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date)), files ([file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file)) and strings ([string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string)).

All of the above tags have 30,000+ questions associated with them, so I've singled these ones out. This is something which causes me extremely mild frustration. Is this a problem?

---

#### A Bit of History

- Back in 2012 a cleanup was proposed, but didn't really ever get enacted ([account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/account) and [accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accounts) still exist, as just one of many examples): [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags).
- The English Stack Exchange site [voted on pluralisation](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags) back in 2014 and pluralisation won (with singularity ending up with a below-zero score of -3).
- The Programmers Stack Exchange site [briefly touched on this](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/should-a-tag-be-singular-or-plural) back in 2010 with a few upvotes towards making things plural.
- The Codegolf Stack Exchange site went with [*whichever one sounds better*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4914/should-tags-be-plural-or-singular) last year.

---

#### Why do I feel this needs to be talked about?

Unless it's a singular thing (like *a* programming language), I feel things which complement other tags should be pluralised. If I ask a question about formatting a date in JavaScript, for example, I'd *want* to be able to tag the question as [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dates), as a date in JavaScript isn't a standalone thing. However at present I can only tag it as [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date).

...yet also at present if I was talking about a variable, I'd have no option but to tag it as [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variables) as the opposite is true for the [variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variables) tag.

If there can be multiple of a thing, why should we keep it singular?

---

Is this a problem and is this something which should be addressed by the community?

Comment: _"Is this a problem and is this something which should be addressed by the community?"_ Asking for [tag:tag-synonyms]?

Comment: Each time I see a plural-vs-singular thing I end up not liking either and voting to burn them all...

Comment: @Braiam Agreed, these seem to be likely useless to make a question more specific regarding particular programming environments or problem cloud.

Comment: This just isn't a problem, nobody ever thinks to use such a tag as the primary [tag] for a question.  Mostly it is the kind that is selected when the questioner just can't think of something better.  At best a contextual tag, not a very good one at that.  You find these back because nobody ever thought it worthwhile to do something about it :)

Comment: ["extremely mild frustration"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQGEBEYPf9g)

Comment: Using plurals is also suggested in Travel Meta: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/336/tags-should-be-plurals-with-a-few-caveats?lq=1

Comment: I would simply regard this as an inevitable side-effect of implementing a [folksonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folksonomy) system, and move on.

Comment: Shouldn't your title read "tags pluralization"? Or should it remain "tag pluralization" and the tag `[tags]` should in fact be `[tag]`? What a dilemma.

Comment: You should be happy you can tag _javascript date variables_! :->

Comment: Since you are addressing other SE sites, shouldn't this question be on [meta.se]?

Comment: Obligatory: [What is the story of Jeff Atwood and the pluralization 'Bug'?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/what-is-the-story-of-jeff-atwood-and-the-pluralization-bug)

Answer (score 8):

Just apply common sense on a case-to-case basis. I think anything else will end up badly:

- "I have a cookie question" (baking advise?)
- "I have a Window question" (carpenter advise?)
- "I have a Pythons question" (reptile advise?)
- "I have a question about <strike>mutex:es</strike>... <strike>mutexes</strike>... <strike>mutices</strike>... many mutex."
- "I have a question about singleton instances."

The list of silliness can go on. There's no universal form.

The meta [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/plurals/info) for [plurals](/questions/tagged/plurals) also provides further useful guidance.

Comment: Some of your examples are deliberately chosen to sound silly. No one would say "Pythons" (plural of the language name) or "Window" (singular of the operating system name). The real question is something like: is `array` or `arrays` the preferred name for a tag dealing with arrays? Also, appealing to common sense is not really a solution: what one sees as common sense other may see as unacceptable