# Why two tags of datatype("datatype" and "datatypes") are present in SO?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was searching for "data type" tag in the tags section of SO, i ended up getting two tags that provide me with the same info(even the related questions are same). So **why are we having two tags for same topic here**(in SO)? [image]

Comment: Because someone once created it, and it was never merged to the other one.

Comment: I guess you are right @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: But something should be done about these either merge both or delete one of them(just to remove the confusion).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318110/do-we-need-to-talk-about-tag-pluralisation

Comment: Lundin answer(to above question) and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags provide a great solution.

Comment: What, exactly, is confusing to you about these tags? They are synonyms of [types]. Seems perfectly appropriate to me.

Comment: CodyGray I am not confused at all with the two tags( I actually used the wrong phrase "confusion" ) after πάντα ῥεῖ comments things are clear to me. Thanks @πάντα ῥεῖ