# Synonymize/Merge tags: [scrollbar] and [scrollbars] (and maybe [browser-scrollbars])

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There's obviously no need for [scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollbar) and [scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollbars). At the time of writing, there's nearly 4000 questions tagged [scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollbar) and a bit over 200 tagged of [scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollbars), so I assume the singular form is what will be kept. 
I'm not sure if ~200 is enough to warrant a synonym rather than a manual retagging. If not, I'll start the manual retagging process.

There are also about 30 questions tagged [browser-scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser-scrollbars), which seems like an unnecessary tag to me, but I figured I'd get some input there in case I'm just overlooking why that's a necessary distinction.

Comment: Please wait for input from the community before any kind of mass-editing, especially since you have less than 2000 rep. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-burninating-tags

Comment: Note that edit by people with less than 2k get rejected for tag edit only, this is because it pollutes the edit queue and asked for 5 users to validate your edit while we have a limited number of review allowed. Which make need more users when there is a lot of those kinds of edits.

Comment: However, if re-tagging is approved by the community, you can safely edit questions that have other problems that need fixed (spelling/wording/formatting/etc) along with the tag change.  Just only do a few at a time so you don't flood the review queue.

Comment: 200 is more than enough to merit a synonym. This is the perfect case for a synonym, in fact. And it avoids the problem of some knucklehead editing 200 questions and making my home page useless for the remainder of the day.

Comment: One could argue that we don't need a tag for either.  I mean, do we really need tags for individual user components?  Do we need a `button` tag as well?

Comment: @casperOne I had that thought too. As for button, we've got 24k questions that thought it was necessary and seperate tags for `back-button` and `share-button`, for some reason

Comment: 24K questions doesn't make it *right*.

Comment: as for the plural/singular case  for scrollbar(s) see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags

Comment: @rene Sadly doesn't give much guidance in this case. Both have wikis. `scrollbar` wiki has more info, but most of the extra looks like it would belong on `browser-scrollbar` (which has no wiki).

Comment: @casperOne I concur. We may very well need a separate discussion on that issue too. I imagine the cleanup to change that would be significantly more involved.