# Synonymize OR replace [exponents] with [exponent], or the two tags with [exponentiation]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I just stumbled upon these tags:

- [exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponent) (240 questions)
- [exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponents) (70 questions)
- [exponentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponentiation) (204 questions)

[exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponent) and [exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponents) seem to be used for questions that are about the same thing: raising a number to some<sup>th</sup> power. They even have identical tag excerpts. As the lower-volume tag, shouldn't [exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponents) be a synonym of [exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponent) or [exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponents) questions go under a retag?

Maybe we can also synonymize/replace [exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponent) and [exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponents) with [exponentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponentiation), but questions tagged with it seem to be concerned about the exponentiation operation itself (e.g the operation's performance) rather than implementing exponentiation.

Comment: These sound like keywords rather than tags. Are they needed at all?

Comment: [This isn't the only one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags)