# Tag synonyms request: dropshadow, drop-shadow and dropshadoweffect

Tags: discussion, status-completed, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Tag synonyms request: [dropshadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropshadow), [drop-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drop-shadow) and [dropshadoweffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropshadoweffect)

They mean the same thing.

Judging by the tag descriptions, [dropshadoweffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropshadoweffect) is specific to some (unspecified) technology, since it mentions bitmaps and textures. But it should become a generic tag like the others, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I checked all the questions in the [dropshadoweffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropshadoweffect) tag. They were all related to WPF, except 3 (which I retagged).

Upon further inspection, I found out that the tag wiki was plagiarized from the documentation for the [DropShadowWiki class documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect?view=netframework-4.8). I have rolled that edit back. We need to create a new and better tag wiki for that tag.

Thus, the tag, [dropshadoweffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropshadoweffect) is not the same as the other two tags, and should not be synonymized. I have already added [drop-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drop-shadow) as a synonym for [dropshadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropshadow), while going through [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags)

Comment: _Thus the tag, dropshadoweffect is not the same as the other tags_ Why? because it is related to WPF? All the tags mean the same thing and tags are meant to tell about the question. If it is a WPF question then it should be tagged with the tag along with one of the dropshadow tags

Comment: `DropShadowEffect` is a class in WPF. It is not the same as the other ones.

Comment: Why are we having different tags for classes now? What matters is that the class does the same thing. Should be tagged with [wpf] and [dropshadow]

Comment: There were always tags for different classes, for example, [tag:bitmapeffect] for the `BitmapEffect` class in WPF, or even [tag:wrapall] for the wrapall function in jQuery. I personally don't like such very specific tag names, but users in general like to use such tags to differentiate/answer quickly, so I am fine with it. (It gets worse in android, where there [android-classname] for loads of tags).