# What's the util(ity) of the [util] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/util) tag has 3 followers, 133 questions, no wiki, and no significant top users — most people have 1, one has 2, a couple have 3, no-one has more for the answerers; the top askers are all 1.  The questions are all over the map — there is no consistency that I can see.

It seems to me to be the quintessential pointless tag, and hence I nominate it for burnination.

---

[Andrew T](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2821954/andrew-t) [points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344013/whats-the-utility-of-the-util-tag?cb=1#comment449320_344013) that there's also the [utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utils) tag which is similarly devoid of usefulness.  It has 3 followers, 72 questions, no wiki, and no significant top users — all the top answerers have but 1 answer; there's a top asker with 2 and everyone else with 1.  The questions are diverse — Java, Javascript, Python and others.

This tag too seems to be both pointless and a candidate for burnination.

Comment: There's also [tag:utils] as per [clean-up singular/plural tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251480/2821954). Also based on top scoring questions, it seems from `java.util` namespace. Doesn't seem useful though.

Comment: It's [inutil](https://www.google.com/search?q=inutil&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)! (spanish is so cool at times)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tags [util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/util) and [utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utils) have been removed from all the afflicted questions.  For some of the Java questions where [java.util.date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.util.date) or [java.util.calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.util.calendar) seemed to be appropriate, the tag was added.

The tag entries have now been removed, too.

[image: ***TROGDOR***]

Comment: So, are we not doing the [burnination process](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-burninating-tags) (from the burninate-request tag info) any more?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan if I want to burninate a tag with 1k question, should I follow the process? How about a hundred? Ten? 3? 1?

Comment: @Braiam That's answered in that link: *If you have basic knowledge of the tag and are capable of burninating the tag in one sitting (give or take 50 questions), you can handle it yourself or with little help.* I'm asking because I wonder what the point of putting in a burnination-request is, if you're just going to do the burnination yourself anyway.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: There was a clear consensus that the tags should go.  I'd forgotten that there is now a protracted process for burninations. The question was to make sure that the removal was acceptable.  These tags were towards the upper-end of the range for the number of questions for which manual processing was tolerable (from the point of view of the person doing the edits).

Comment: Part of the process involves getting the burnination request featured, which allows more people to see the request than just Meta regulars. In this case, I doubt that would have changed the outcome: you've been on here long enough to know what a bad tag is. I was just curious if maybe I missed something.