# Visual distinction of deprecated/discouraged tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Can we make do-not-use tags visually distinct in some way? I almost used one just now, because I typed in the tags quickly, so I started typing the next tag before the autocomplete had showed up for the first tag. I'm guessing this is a lesser problem for people in the US, since the latency is lower.

The tag I almost used was [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history), which has a "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" at the start of the description.

I guess I'd also like a visual distinction when typing in a previously non-existant tag, since it's most likely a typo.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to not allow people to use such tags? The current way didn't require any modification of the site (that's why it is used), but if they are going to implement a workflow for discouraging tags, shouldn't it then be something more complete than just coloring tag names?

Comment: I agree with BDL. Normally, such tags get burninated, but [the backlog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bburninate-request%5D+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D+score%3A20+is%3Aquestion) currently contains 209 questions (and tags). I strongly agree that we should have a way discourage or completely block usage of these tags in the mean time.

Comment: "Why are some of my tags red? (And No, for Reasons I did not bother to read the associated text. What, was there something important there?)"

Comment: Your example tag `history` is actually a pretty good indicator that a mere *text* is not enough, even when capitalized. There are good reasons not to delete DNU tags (... what where they?) but would it be possible to list them but make'm not selectable? As it is, the only indication of their badness is the capitalized text itself.

Comment: We could also leverage the [how-to-ask tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips) to inform users that don't read the text, and don't care a tag is red.

Comment: _I guess I'd also like a visual distinction when typing in a previously non-existant tag, since it's most likely a typo._ That sounds like a different feature request to me. You'd best ask it in a separate question, so we can count votes as agreement/disagreement on a singular request.

Comment: For tags that are almost likely a typo, the system lets you type them down but hints you, by not showing autocompletition, that it doesn't exist. Also, there's a warning if you are creating a new tag (cc @eric)

Comment: Not sure why they would spend development time to show this kind of warning. There are already processes for destroying tags and black-listing them so they don't return. What's in there to gain with this? Just start burnination/blacklisting requests, would make more sense. Having a tag that cannot be used is the same as not having the tag at all, imo.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth just noticed some of the requests in that query are done, but not marked as such by the mods - e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344013/whats-the-utility-of-the-util-tag?s=2|6.0235.  Think it's worth me going through it and opening a new question to ask the mods mark them as done if done?

Comment: @dsolimano you can modflag individual questions and ask to get them marked as status-completed. Good catch!

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth thanks will do

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: there are some [good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271356) to not blindly remove them.

Comment: @usr2564301 What you linked practically says "they are useless"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I agree they are; it wasn't my point.

Comment: @usr2564301 Then what was your point? You sounded like I was crazy yet provided a link that supports my comment

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: the process of removing the tags where applied and deciding whether to add new ones is a manual process, requiring quite a bit of cooperation to remove even a single tag from existence (mostly coordinated through a Burnination request here on Meta). As I understand it, there is a huge backlog already.

Comment: Here's a solution we can all agree on: prefix discouraged tags with [](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F4A9/)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto They don't want to just automatically delete any given tag, and the manual process takes time, during which the tag gets added to more questions, thus increasing the work required to delete the tag, making it take more time, so it gets added to more questions in the mean time, etc., etc. - I think the real problem is the fact that blacklisting is considered an extreme step which they only do very rarely (typically reserved for tags that keep coming back after burninations).

Comment: @Dukeling I didn't say it should be done automatically. But if you will use development time to create a feature whose ONLY purpose is to not even prevent tags from being used, just "visually discourage" their use, I find it completely useless. Use the development time to make a feature for easier blacklisting and burnination instead.

Comment: Related: [Give moderators the ability to manage blacklisted tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125812) and [Allow 10K users to vote on suggested blacklist tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61354) (both pretty old though)

Comment: I want to upvote this to show my agreement with the fact that something needs to change here, but I want to downvote this because I think discouraging usage will have little to no effect - we need to **prevent** usage.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that this is a bad feature request. I find it hard to understand why the engineers at SO would take the time to create a feature whose ultimate point is useless.

If a tag cannot be used (hence "DO NOT USE"), it should be burninated and then blacklisted. There's no purpose in creating a feature for discouraging the use of these tags that will, sooner or later, be removed from the system. If anything, the feature request should be to completely prevent (i.e disable/hide) the use of these tags after the community approves (maybe through posts here on Meta).

Comment: Burnination takes time.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I didn't say it doesn't. Tools could/ *should* be created to help the community with that

Comment: Having a color code for tags undergoing burnination is a nice tool to help with that. People will think twice when they see something like bright-red tag.

Answer (score 1):

This would be hard to enforce because anyone can edit a tag to add that verbiage in.

To play fair, I'm imagining such a system, which would allow users at 20k rep to vote on a tag as burninated and then must link to a burnination meta question for that tag. If five 20k users vote on the tag and link to the same burnination meta question, maybe it enters a mod queue or something that allows the tag to be blacklisted.

This kind of process would be very different from how the system works today, and would require a lot of effort from the developers, as well as place a lot more trust in far fewer users. Currently the process is entirely manual, which does mean it takes far longer, but also affords the site the ability to rely on input from scores, if not hundreds, of active meta users before a tag is considered for burnination, and then blacklisting.

In summation, I don't see this kind of thing happening any time soon, though a more automated system would be nice.

Comment: I would expect that we would be able to vote on tag obsolescence the same way we're currently voting for tag synonyms.

Comment: @Bergi I thought so too at first but I'm not sure if there wouldn't be a conflict of interest in people invested in a tag voting for its demise.

Comment: Oops you're right, I always forget that you need to have answered a few questions for synonym votes, it's not just rep-based unfortuntely.