# Show tag wikis on mobile website

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

I couldn't find a way to read the tag wiki on the mobile website (which is what I feel like I have to use, since the android app hasn't been updated in half a year).

Given that tag wikis are used to [mark tags as deprecated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361303/visual-distinction-of-deprecated-discouraged-tags) it would be nice if I could actually read them. I'd bet we're getting a ton of new questions on deprecated tags this way.