# Alias [fixtures] or [fixture]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixtures) and [fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixture) are both for unit test fixtures. I propose that one is made as an alias of the other. Which one should remain as the primary tag?

Comment: People seem to overwhelmingly use `[fixtures]`. 839 vs 124. That seems like a good starting place.

Comment: Related: [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251478) (this pair of tag is on [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251480/2821954)), and yes, the next step is to decide which one is the master tag (this meta post).