# Merge [visitor] into [visitor-pattern]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Today I was looking for more information about the visitor design pattern, but looking for it I noticed that both the [visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visitor) tag (339) and [visitor-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visitor-pattern) tag (225) are used for the same topic. The [visitor-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visitor-pattern) tag excerpt even mentions:

> This tag is a synonym of the more frequently used [visitor]; please
>   use [visitor] rather than this tag.

Eventhough it states that they are synonyms, they are not marked as such.

Can we merge those together? I'm personally in favor of using [visitor-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visitor-pattern) as it is immediately clear that it is about a design pattern. "Visitor" is in my opinion a bit too generic.

Comment: What the heck is this tag useful for?

Comment: Someone would need to look through questions with the [[tag:visitor]] tag and verify that it is actually being used to refer to the visitor pattern. If not, then some manual clean-up will be required before we can merge.

Comment: @CodyGray I think a cleanup might be required. A quick look (first 2 pages) identified [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585954/show-recently-viewed-product-in-magento-to-guest-users), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069202/trace-sighup-visitors-of-my-apple-application) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329087/need-the-keywords-search-details-form-a-particular-country) question about website/app visitors (note that the last one is tagged [tag:visitor-pattern] too because it's about identifying patterns in website visitors.

Comment: @CodyGray Do you know if there's going to be an "official" cleanup effort for this tag? I just ran into this too, actually - it seems weird to have two separate tags that (supposedly) have the exact same meaning.

Comment: I ran into this as well, @EJoshuaS, while taking [care of the singular-plural tag cleanup post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags). There is no official clean up effort, per se, but given that it's just a cleanup, feel free to collect a few other like minded users and start the cleanup. Ping me once it is done, so that I can merge the tags.

Answer (score 3):

Most questions using [visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visitor) seems to be about the visitor pattern. However, a fair amount of questions also uses the tag for questions about visitors to web sites. I believe that the tag is ambiguous, roughly 10-20% of the questions seem to be about other things.

If the tags are to be merged, we would first have to go through [visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visitor) and fix all questions that use the tag incorrectly.

If some automatic re-tagging is available, then after cleanup, all [visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visitor) should be re-tagged to [visitor-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visitor-pattern). After which we can get rid of [vistior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vistior) entirely - I don't see the benefit of merging the tags.

Comment: And I got the perfect burninante pun: _get rid of unwanted [tag:visitor]_. (This question is now in step 0 of the burninate procedure, where we are trying to come up with silly puns even before we have decided what to do with the tag.)

Comment: Yes, automated retagging is available. In particular, *merging* one tag into another (which also covers renames). Takes a couple of clicks for a moderator to do. But yeah, I agree that [[tag:visitor]] needs to be cleaned up first, while we can still find those questions easily. If you wanted to ultimately remove the [[tag:visitor]] tag, you'd merge but not create a synonym. That would change the tags in the database without introducing revision history, but since you didn't create a synonym, the orphaned tag would die within 24 hours.