# Duplicate tags [implicit] and [implicits]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit) and [implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicits) look the same to me (both are related to Scala implicit parameters and conversions).

The first one (singular) seems better described to me. Could the other one be made an alias or removed completely?

Comment: Note that this combination is already on the list to clean up [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251480/7296893), with many others. Any reason to expedite the cleanup? (I don't know exactly how soon tags from that list are merged, if at all)