# Tag synonym request for [function-call] and [function-calls]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

It seems to me that the two tags [function-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-call) (2 watchers) and [function-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-calls) (0 watchers) are both in-use (although rarely - both roughly 300 questions). To me it seems like these could be synonyms, but I don't have the required "score" to propose a synonym for any of these.

My question is actually rather simple: Do you think it makes sense to make one of these a synonym of the other? And if the answer is "yes" could someone propose the synonym?

Comment: It's also brought up in the great [Cleanup of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags)