# Synonym [folder] and [folders]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folder) - 4367 questions

> A folder or directory is a virtual container within a digital file system, in which groups of computer files and other folders can be kept and organized.

[folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folders) - 1353 questions

> "Folders" is a plural of folder. A folder or directory is a virtual container within a digital filesystem, in which groups of computer files and other folders can be kept and organized.

So [folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folders) is trying to be cute. It copies the [folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folder) excerpt and adds *"Folders" is a plural of folder.*

Thank you Captain Obvious...

I can't see any good reason why we need a plural tag here. If you're working on one folder or 1000, [folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folder) should be sufficient to describe what you're working on.

Comment: "I can't see any good reason why we need,,," any of these tags.

Comment: It's in the [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251478/7296893) list. Progress on that list has been slow, but any reason to move faster on this one?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth No particular reason. Ran across it doing a burninate. The tags are too large for any manual work, tho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folders) has been merged into [folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folder)

```
updating post history, 1620 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 1353 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 1317 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, new count: 5680
tag remapping of [folder] and [folders] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
14 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
129 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym folders -> folder was approved!
```