# Merge request: [decimalformat] and [decimal-format]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There really isn't much to say here. The two tags have the same exact description with the only difference being a hyphen between the two words. The answer seems obvious.

[decimalformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decimalformat) and [decimal-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decimal-format)

Here is their description:

`The Java class DecimalFormat is a concrete subclass of NumberFormat that is used to format decimal numbers. Use this tag only for questions about this Java class, not for general decimal formatting.`

Is there any reason to keep them separate?

Comment: Did you just see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230331/how-to-print-a-0-in-front-of-a-decimal-when-the-value-is-0-98 too?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah that was my inspiration for this post

Comment: Me, too. We both posted simultaneously, so we couldn't see the duplication. How ironic to have duplicate questions about duplicate tags. :)

Comment: This is covered in [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251478/4642212).