# Should we create [docx4js] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

This is [docx4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docx4j) (which already exists), which is for Java: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j

This is docx4js, which is for JavaScript: https://github.com/lalalic/docx4js

I see the following error when I try to create it:

> You are attempting to create the tag [docx4js]; however the tag [docx4j] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.

Can we please create a [docx4js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docx4js) tag?

Comment: You only need [1500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) for doing so.

Comment: At 5K you should be able to add the tag wiki as well. Did it not let you add the tag to your question?

Comment: Nope.@BSMP  I see the following error when I try to create it:  "You are attempting to create the tag [docx4js]; however the tag [docx4j] already exists!  If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta"

Answer (score 5):

The reason you couldn't create the [docx4js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docx4js) is because the system assumed it's a pluralized form of [docx4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docx4j) and prevented it (there's a history about it on [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags/251480#251480)).

However, moderators can bypass the restriction, and the tag has been created.