# Synonymize [sqlparameter] with [sqlparameters]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

From a quick scan across the question tagged with [sqlparameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameters) it looks like this tag should be a synonym of [sqlparameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameter).

However, a search for [`\[sqlparameters\] -\[c#\] -\[.net\]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameters+-c%23+-.net) still returns 71 questions out of total 180.

Could we synonymize them together? If not, can we provide tag-wiki for [sqlparameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameters) to make it clear why it is a separate tag?

Comment: A follow up Q: What is the difference between these 2 and [tag:mysql-parameter]?

Answer (score 1):

This was proposed amongst the 325 synonyms earlier, during the [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251480/4099593), but I had skipped over it because it did seem like there were two different use cases for them, given that a lot of questions were referring to "SQL Parameters" and tagged with [sqlparameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameters) (And I also really wanted to synonymize only the very obvious ones because there were 325 of them, and it would have been very hard to detect a wrong synonym).

Now that I see this again, it is quite clear that they are referring to the same concept, which is the [SQLParameter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.8) class. The questions describe them as "SQL Parameters" while using this same class.

I have added [sqlparameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameters) as a synonym for [sqlparameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameter), that is [sqlparameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameters) (x 180) → [sqlparameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameter) (x 99), because 1. SQLParameter is the name of the class. 2. [sqlparameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameter) has a tag wiki. I will wait for a few days before merging the tags, so that it can be reversed in the case of a dispute.