# Rename the [web-component] tag to [web-components]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

The tag [web-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-component) is wrong. It should be [web-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-components).

Comment: I’m not convinced.

Comment: Here's their website https://www.webcomponents.org/. I'm a person easily irritated by spellings and typos.

Comment: WebComponents is a collection of web components. The tag [web-component] is about web components, not WebComponents.

Comment: OK, so this tag is blocking the tag for `web components` from being created.

Comment: That site (and its GitHub repo) hasn’t been updated in quite a while. Seems like the project might be failing. Custom Elements is the primary standard anyway, and what most people talk about when discussing “web components”.

Comment: Maybe I should use this url https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components.

Comment: Indeed, very similar tags. Interestingly, "webcomponents" could also mean the website webcomponents.org. Try [webcomponents-org].

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments these tags are different.

[web-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-component) should be used for web components, a set of features that allow the creation of custom and encapsulated HTML tags to use easily in a page. See more in [the tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-component/info) and [MDN Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components).

[web-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-components) hasn't been created (yet). However, if it had been, it would refer to the [WebComponents website](https://www.webcomponents.org) or to [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/webcomponents) and would therefore confuse people.

Some related meta posts about singular vs. plural tagging (looks like singular is preferred):

- [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251478)
- [Old MSE question about singular vs. plural tag names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41501/tagging-as-singular-or-plural)