# Are [channels] comprised of [channel]s?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Are [channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/channels) comprised of [channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/channel)s?

I think we should merge [channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/channels) into [channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/channel), as the former has fewer questions, no tag wiki or excerpt.

And more importantly, they are synonymous, aren't they?

Comment: This seems really straightforward; this is one of the cases synonyms are designed for.

Comment: Maybe there's a case for [channel] being an ambiguous tag, but the plural should still be synonymized.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags) (second answer, indicating it needs to be disambiguated first)