# Should we rename the [avd] tag to [android-virtual-device]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Could we agree to rename the [avd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avd) tag to the much more informative name
[android-virtual-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-virtual-device)?
I think the tag name cannot be any shorter than that,
at least not without losing important information on what the tag is about. The tag currently has 2500+ questions.

And then maybe make [avd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avd) a synonym of [android-virtual-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-virtual-device), if that's appropriate?

### References

- [Tag wiki for the [avd] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/avd/info)
- [Post on how to name tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251478)

Comment: Thanks! Greatly appreciated. 